# ES6 Filter array of object were a property exists

Tags: object, ecmascript-6, properties, find, exists

I am trying to filter an array of objects to return just the objects that have property the other objects do not have. Not a value in a property, but the property itself.

```
results [
   { 
      "title": "Foo",
      "value":  34
   },
   {
       "value": 43
   },
   {
       "title": "The Title",
       "value": 99
]
```

In the example above I want the first and last object as they have a 'title' property, in an new array of objects.

I looked at 'filter' but it seems to work with values..  How do I this?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can filter items like following code, it filters if title property exists.

```js
    const items = [
       { 
          "title": "Foo",
          "value":  34
       },
       {
           "value": 43
       },
       {
           "title": "The Title",
           "value": 99
       }
    ];
    

    const filteredItems = items.filter(item => !!item.title)
```

Comment: What does !! mean in JS?

Comment: @IlijaIličić

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript

Answer (score 5):

Use [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) wrapper, it's more clear:

```
const filteredItems = items.filter(item => Boolean(item.title))
```